# 'SYMBOL' object is not callable

Tags: python, sympy

this is my first time with sympy and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Could you help me please?

This is my code:

```
from __future__ import division
from sympy import *

q, l, p = symbols('q, l, p')
x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7 = symbols('x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7')
c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7 = symbols('c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7')
c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14 = symbols('c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14')


a = 209 * q * l / 42 - p / 3
"TRECHO AB"
m1 = a * x1 - q * x1 ** 2 / 2
d1 = integrate(m1, x1) + c1
y1 = integrate(d1, x1) + c2

"TRECHO BC"
m2 = a * 2 * l + a * x2 - 2 * q * l(x2 + l)
d2 = integrate(m2, x2) + c3
y2 = integrate(d2, x2) + c4

"TRECHO CD"
m3 = a(3 * l + x3) - 2 * q * l(2 * l + x3) - q * x3 ** 3 / 6 * l
d3 = integrate(m3, x3) + c5
y3 = integrate(d3, x3) + c6

"TRECHO DE"
m4 = a(x4 + 6 * l) - 2 * q * l(x4 + 5 * l) - (9 * q * l / 2)(x4 + l)
d4 = integrate(m4, x4) + c7
y4 = integrate(d3, x4) + c8

"TRECHO FG"
m5 = a(x5 + 7 * l) - 2 * q * l(x5 + 6 * l) - (9 * q * l / 2)(x5 + 2 * l) - p * x5
d5 = integrate(m5, x5) + c9
y5 = integrate(d5, x5) + c10

"TRECHO GH"
m6 = a(x6 + 15 * l / 2) - 2 * q * l(x6 + 13 * l / 2) - (9 * q * l / 2)(x6 + 5 * l / 2) - p(x6 + l / 2) - 2 * q * x6(
    x6 / 2)
d6 = integrate(m6, x6) + c11
y6 = integrate(d6, x6) + c12

"TRECHO HI"
m7 = a(x7 + 19 * l / 2) - 2 * q * l(x7 + 17 * l / 2) - (9 * q * l / 2)(x7 + 9 * l / 2) - p(x7 + 5 * l / 2) - 4 * q * l(
    x7 + l) - (3 * q * x7 ** 2 / 2 * l)(x7 / 3)
d7 = integrate(m7, x7) + c13
y7 = integrate(d7, x7) + c14

print(
    "{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{},\n{}".format(d1, y1, d2, y2, d3, y3, d4, y4, d5, y5,
                                                                                 d6, y6, d7, y7))
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mecsolidos2.py", line 17, in <module>
    m2 = a * 2 * l + a * x2 - 2 * q * l(x2 + l)
TypeError: 'Symbol' object is not callable
```

That is the same error to m3 through m7 :S
I've tried to change m2 to another constant, used m2 as m2.eval but none of that worked :S
What pissed me of was that for m1 it worked perfectly

ps: sorry for my bad english

Comment: What is `l(x2 + l)` supposed to be doing?  `l` is defined as a `sympy symbol`.  `fn(...)` is python syntax for calling (running) a function, or more generally a `callable`.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with `numpy`, are you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If l() is intended as a function, it should be declared somewhere. If you wish, in SymPy you can have functions without giving its internal details, e.g. as `l = Function('l')(x)`. More details in the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/).

If, on the contrary, `l(...)` is meant to be just a multiplication (as suggested by your symbols declaration and the use of `l` as a scalar elsewhere), the multiplication (`*`) needs to be written explicitly.

Note that for SymPy to work optimally, when declaring symbols, it helps to specify their type. For example `symbols(".....", real=True)`. Also, specifying whether some variable is always positive can help, especially when logarithms or sqrt are involved. See the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#assumptions) for more details about the possible types of assumptions.

By the way, if you prefer a looser syntax, where the multiplication symbol can be omitted and `^` can get converted to `**`, the [`sympify()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.sympify) or [`parse_expr()`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) functions might be interesting.